# background color in different post in wordpress\

Tags: php, css, wordpress

http://malitechnolab.com/solarzenith.com/ this is my website. I have try adding different type of color in all post. but it is not full width. how to add full width post background color in wordpress

Comment: it will not go full width , as you are wrapping the elements inside `.container` class of css , and that class is containing an `max-width` property , so basically you have to override that.

Comment: `body {
    background: #4ec6ab none repeat scroll 0 0;
}` That's?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

because the div is child of the **container** which is really not full **width**. Try to separate the **article section** from **container** and add class a **container-fluid** on it and put your **Background color**. Like this:
see demo.https://jsfiddle.net/he58pxz0/1/

```
<section class="container-fluid" style="background:red">
<div class="container"></div>
</section>
```